# How can i change the collation for the tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem that i exported tables from the database , there is two tables name like `el_gAnnouncement` and another table `el_gannouncement`

there is error in the phpmyadmin when I'm trying to import table to the database

> SQL query:
>
> -- -- Dumping data for table `el_gAnnouncement` -- INSERT INTO `el_gAnnouncement` (`gAnn_id`, `gAnn_text`, `gAnn_order`,
>   `gAnn_status`, `gAnn_date`, `gAnn_expiration`) VALUES (4,
>   0x4575726f4c696e676f2070617274696369706174657320696e204c6f63616c697a6174696f6e20576f726c6420436f6e666572656e636520323031302e,
>   1, 'Yes', '2011-04-04 09:51:42', '0000-00-00'), (5,
>   0x4575726f4c696e676f5c277320526570726573656e74617469766520696e2054656b6f6d20323031303a205c2254656b6f6d2032303130207761732061207375636365737366756c20657870657269656e636520666f72204575726f4c696e676f5c22,
>   1, 'Yes', '2010-12-29 02:36:42', '0000-00-00'), (6,
>   0x4575726f4c696e676f20657870616e6473206974732072616e6b73206f662050726f6a656374204d616e61676572732c206163636f7264696e6720746f20746865206f6e676f696e6720657870616e73696f6e20706c616e2e,
>   2, 'Yes', '2010-12-29 02:37:09', '0000-00-00'), (7,
>   0x4575726f4c696e676f20696e74726f6475636573206d6f7265206c616e677561676520706169727320746f20697473206c697374206f66206c616e67756167652070616972732e,
>   3, 'Ye[...]
>
> MySQL said:
>
> ## 1062 - Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY'

how can i solve this problem .. i think may be the problem with the table collations in my localhost ... the two table were on the server with no problem with collation `latin1_swedish_ci`

what is the best way to import the tables ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's not what the error is saying. It is saying that you already have a value '4' in your primary key. I don't know how using the wrong character code would cause this. If fact I don't see any data that would actually be affected by an improper character code. The problem is you are trying to insert value 4 into  gAnn_id but that value already exists. You need to check your mysql dump for duplicate gAnn_ids or even duplicate insert rows. What options did you use in phpmyadmin for export? Was the table you are inserting to empty? If not, that is probably your problem. To fix it export without the gAnn_id column and let the new database assign a new one based on auto-increment. If you need to keep the ids the same either the current ids on the target database have to change or the new ids have to change. Take your pick.

If you still want to know about changing collation. Check out the Mysql manual.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-table.html